# Apps Script Refused to Connect

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-sites, x-frame-options

I am trying to learn Apps Script and some fron-end web dev. I wrote some some code in Apps Script and I am trying to render it in a Google Site.

Here is the doGet function that I use in my Apps Script:

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index');
  return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

Interestingly, the script renders itself when I use the Google-given URL:
https://sites.google.com/corp/view/vrajlinkshortener

However, that is not the case when I enter the custom domain:
www.wharton.ml

I checked the documentation and I still could not figure out why a custom domain would prohibit Apps Script form working.

Any tips? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the option `XFrameOptionsMode` to `ALLOWALL`.

## XFrameOptionsMode

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/x-frame-options-mode

> Setting XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL will let any site iframe the page, so the developer should implement their own protection against clickjacking.

```
return template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
```

As stated in the comments below ([Shan Eapen Koshy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57138352/apps-script-refused-to-connect/57139742#comment119612327_57139742) said) check that your browser is logged into one Google account only.

Comment: After adding   return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(e.parameter['page'])
                    .evaluate()
                    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
                    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);, I still get error "script.google.com refused to connect." This is surely not the answer.

Comment: @k.b, can you share your code? You need to re-deploy your current deployment.

Comment: If anyone is facing the "refused to connect" issue even after following the above answer, try the iframe embed in an incognito window. If it's loading there, it probably is caused by having multiple Google accounts signed in. It's still a problem with GAS.

Comment: Also don't forget to create a new deployment for your project after making the changes and update the link in your iframe tag. I wasted 10 mins thinking that saving the code on the online IDE would automatically update the my current deployment.

Answer (score -2):

Just add below, it is working

```
function doGet(e){
  var temp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('html')
  return temp.evaluate().setTitle("Booking Window").setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME).setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
}
```